# What does がんばっぺ mean?

Tags: words, meaning, dialects

Today I got a mail from my company but I am unable to figure out the meaning of がんばっぺ！！.

The sentence is as follows-

> 下期も 製図勉強会や(秘)レクレーション大会などを
>   予定しております。
>
> 水戸のみなさん、一緒に**がんばっぺ**！！

Is it similar to がんばれ？

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A0%91%E5%BC%B5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BA)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see in your e-mail, that you mention 水戸｛みと｝市.

頑張っペ is 茨城弁｛いばらきべん｝. `っぺ` is typically used to replace volitional form よう/おう　sounds. It is used on this sign for example:

[image: Ibaraki-ben sign]

Thus, I would translate your example into `頑張ろう` !

Note that using `っぺ` has other uses, see the [wikipedia entry](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8C%A8%E5%9F%8E%E5%BC%81) if you feel up to it. The main other use is to make a guess, a conjecture.

Example:

> そっぢは食べもんがうまかっぺー？

Taken from [this thread](http://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2012/0511/506518.htm?g=01)